# How to grep the pidof bash in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get the PID of bash and highlight it if it's in some textfile (assume it is). So when I'm typing this in my shell:

```
grep -o $(pidof bash) test.txt
```

it just works fine and gives me the desired output, the PID of bash.
Then why is this script not working:

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$(grep -o $(pidof bash) test.txt)
echo $PID
```

I only get some lines with:

> grep: xxx: file or directory not found

xxx are random numbers, but usually the last one is the one I'm looking for.

How do I achieve this and why is the above not working?

Has this something to do with creating a new process by the shell when calling grep in the script?

Thank you.

Comment: `$BASH_PID` is the appropriate tool to use, or `$$` (depending on just which shell's PID you want -- the parent shell, or the subshell started by `$()`).

Comment: ...`pidof` is, generally speaking, a tool best avoided unless you can find no better way to identify a specific process -- any given system will have *lots* of bash instances running at any given time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have `pidof`, so I'm assuming that it's an equivalent to `pgrep -v`, printing a list of PIDs, one on each line, with a newline between them.

If that's so, consider this:

```
egrep -o "$(pgrep -v bash | tr '\n' '|')" test.txt
```

Assume that the output of `pgrep -v bash` is:

```
123
456
789
```

Your original code would do this:

```
egrep -o 123 456 789 test.txt
```

...thus, searching for `123` in a file named `456`, in a file named `789`, and in a file named `test.txt`.

---

Now, compare to what happens when you replace that whitespace with pipe symbols:

```
egrep -o "123|456|789" test.txt
```

...as executed by the pipeline suggested earlier in this question is exactly what you were looking for. (BTW, the quotes here are purely syntactic -- that is, they're for consumption by the shell when it's understanding how things are parsed, not passed to `egrep`).

---

That said, if you're looking for the **current** bash process, use either `$$` (for the parent PID of the current shell) or `$BASH_PID` (for the current shell itself *even if it's a subshell*), rather than using so inexact a tool as `pgrep` or `pidof`.

Answer (score 1):

When you run `pidof` inside your shell script, there are at least two instances of bash running, so it will return multiple numbers.  The way grep is designed, it can only search for one pattern at a time so the first number is interpreted as a pattern and the other numbers are mistakenly interpreted as file or directory names.

I'm not sure which bash PID you care about, but one solution is to use something like `grep`, `head`, or `tail` to filter the output of `pidof` so you just get one number.  Another solution is to use the special variable `$$`, which is the PID of bash instance that evaluates it.

In the future, you can debug this better for yourself.  To debug, I would start by running this command inside your script to see exactly what arguments are being passed to `grep`:

```
echo grep -o $(pidof bash) test.txt
```

Comment: `$$` isn't *quite* what you describe it as -- if you have a subshell, `$$` expands to the parent shell's PID, so you'd actually want `$BASH_PID` instead if the goal is to identify that subshell.

Comment: Also, `echo` isn't a great tool. I'd suggest `printf '%q ' grep -o $(pidof bash) test.txt; echo` -- that way you're passing things through literally, such that `printf '%q ' grep -o "$(pidof bash)" test.txt; echo` would look different, whereas with the `echo`, fixing the quotes (while it changes the actual behavior greatly) has no visible effect on the output.

Comment: `set -x` is another preferable alternative, a little bit less verbose than the whole `printf %q` mouthful. `set -x` will put the shell in debug mode where it prints every command before executing it until turned off with `set -x`, and prints it *in such a way as to make quoting, whitespace, and other content elided by `echo` explicit*.